# Add missing/extra values in data array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have recorded WiFi CSI sensor data 5000 packets in 5 seconds(5000 packets x 57 subcarriers). But due to dynamic hardware configuration sometimes I only receive 4998 x 57. I want to add and estimate 2 rows so that my original design has consistent 5000 rows x 57 columns.

[image: Sample Data]

As you can see some data are 5000x57, and some are 4998x57.

Comment: Well of course you can just add 2 rows to your arrays, but the question is, what data do you want in those rows? an extrapolation of the values at the end of the array? `0`-rows? Or whatever?

Comment: "We address this issue with mean imputation. We pad the missing waveforms with the mean of the waveforms we receive at that time step. Since all the waveforms we receive in a single time step are highly correlated", I was reading a paper they used this technique.

Comment: That is not enough information for me to help you, because I don't know how "waveforms" and "timesteps" are represented in your data. I would assume a you got one row per timestep so 5000 timesteps per array, correct? and each column is a "waveform" or what? so 57 waveforms?

Comment: each column is a point in the waveform. 5000x1 is one waveform of one carrier recorded in 5 seconds, one value per ms. and 57 waveforms.

Comment: So let me get this straight: You want to append 2 rows to your arrays which hold the average value of each column?

Comment: yes and since I am new to matlab I don't quite understand different code available on mathworks for append and estimate separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output using `mean()`-function combined with the concatenation operator `[]` and the `repmat()` like this:

```
A=randi(100,4998,57);
A=[A;repmat(mean(A),2,1)];
```

Most of the functions in Matlab that take arrays as an input will calculate for each column except if the input array hast just 1 row. So does the mean function and you can just append means output to your arrays.
If you show me the code that you used to import the data, I might be able to help you create a cleaner data structure and thus be able to automatically process all of your arrays. The way the data is currently designed it's only possible to do this with dynamic variable names which is considered bad programming practice.